# Remove a sublayer from TextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, calayer, uitextborderstyle

I need two functions, One to add a bottom boarder and one to remove a bottom boarder. How can I remove this boarder I have created?

```
extension UITextField {
    func addBottomBorder(){
        let bottomLine = CALayer()
        bottomLine.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - 1, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 1)
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
    }
    func removeBottomBorder(){        
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a subclass of `UITextField`, some other class or are they extensions of the `UITextField`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to remove the layer with `.removeFromSuperlayer()` so hold a reference to it

```
extension UITextField {

    func addBottomBorder(){

         let bottomLine = CALayer()
         bottomLine.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - 1, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 1)
         bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
         self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)


     }
     func removeBottomBorder() {
         self.layer.sublayers?.first?.removeFromSuperlayer()
     }
}
```

for safety that you may add other sublayers

```
extension UITextField {

  func addBottomBorder(){
     let bottomLine = UIView()
     bottomLine.tag = 23
     bottomLine.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - 1, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 1)
     bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
     self.addSubview(bottomLine)
  }
  func removeBottomBorder() {
    self.subviews.forEach {
        if $0.tag == 23 {
            $0.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would I place this in my Extension?

Comment: This worked perfectly :) Thanks so much! I only have one sublayer so the first solution of fine for me